# How to check if mouse pointer touches a UI Element (In my case a circle) in C# and XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to find out if my mouse pointer touches or enters a UI Elemnt. Currently i am using UIElement.PointerEntered event [UIElement.PointerEntered event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerentered.) 
but it only works if I move my pointer and if it touches the UI Element i.e:- if my UI Element is moving and if it touches the pointer which isn't moving then the event won't be triggered. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem occurs only when the UIElement is moving, then how do you move the UIElement? If you use a RenderTransform, try a LayoutTransform instead because the latter includes measure and arrange updates.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use other event called MouseEnter 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx

There are other events available too such as MouseOver

Comment: I am not able to use any Mouse events or properties. I am only able to use the pointer events. Eg:- I am unable to use UIElement.MouseEnter but UIElement.Pointer is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the OnPropertyChanged method and check if the IsMouseOver property has changed

Comment: I am not able to use any Mouse events or properties. I am only able to use the pointer events.
Eg:- I am unable to use UIElement.MouseEnter but UIElement.Pointer is working.